# How to change UIButton border color when button is highlighted (or tapped on) in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, mobile, uibutton, swift3

This is what I have as of now. Would Like to know how to change the border color of the button when it has been tapped or highlighted. So far, I have only been able to do this with the button's text color. Any help or tips would be great, thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var createNewWorkoutButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func createWorkoutBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createNewWorkoutButton.setTitleColor(UIColor .gray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)

    if createNewWorkoutButton = UIControlState.highlighted {
        createNewWorkoutButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the color while touch is **DOWN** and revert it back while touch is **UP**, just use `isHighlighted` by subclassing **UIButton** which I think is a cleaner approach. like so:

**First scenario:**

[image]

```
     class MyButton: UIButton
    {
        override var isHighlighted: Bool {
            didSet {
                switch isHighlighted {
                case true:
                    layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                    layer.borderWidth = 2
                case false:
                    layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                    layer.borderWidth = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now if you have many buttons and you want the user to be aware of the selected button you can try the code below even though I know there most be many other approaches to achieve this but this was the quickest way I came up with.
the code explains itself.

**Second scenario:**

[image]

```
    class Something: UIView {
        private lazy var firstButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
        }()

        private lazy var secondButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
        }()

        private lazy var thirdButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
        }()

        @objc
        private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let myButtons = [self.firstButton, self.secondButton, self.thirdButton]

            for button in vatButtons {
                // state 1 means the button is on Selected State
                (button.state.rawValue == 1) ? button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor : (button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to attach targets for the touchUp and touchDown actions like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   createNewWorkoutButton.setTitleColor(UIColor .gray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)

   createNewWorkoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setButtonSelected(button:)), for: .touchDown);
   createNewWorkoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setButtonSelected(button:)), for: .touchUpInside);

}

func setButtonSelected(button : UIButton) {
    //layout for selected state
}

func setButtonUnselected(button : UIButton) {
    //layout for unselected state
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a background image(border style) for high light state. e.g.:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(createNewWorkoutButton.frame.size);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor);
    context?.setLineWidth(1.0);
    context?.stroke(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: createNewWorkoutButton.frame.size.width,
                                 height: createNewWorkoutButton.frame.size.height));
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    createNewWorkoutButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.highlighted);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!